# Memgraph support for NetworkX algorithms

Tags: python, networkx, graph-algorithm, memgraphdb

Is there an easy way to work with `Memgraph` & `NetworkX`? `NetworkX` has a huge library of algorithms, and I would like to be able to run them on data I have stored inside `Memgraph`.

Also, does Memgraph offer any out of the box graph algorithms?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, it's possible. Memgraph has a pretty tight integration with NeworkX. Take a look [here](https://docs.memgraph.com/memgraph/reference-overview/networkx) for the details.

Comment: That seems to be a new feature. It wasn't there last time I check, about 2 weeks ago. I'll download the latest version of Memgraph and give it a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In [Memgraph 2.4](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/reference-guide/built-in-graph-algorithms) ASP algorithm was introduce into the core. So now Memgraph comes with following algorithms right out of the box:

- Depth-first search (DFS)
- Breadth-first search (BFS)
- Weighted shortest path (WSP)
- All shortest paths (ASP)

Another set of algorithms is available in MAGE. It is an open-source repository that contains graph algorithms and modules written by the team behind Memgraph and its users in the form of query modules.

MAGE includes the following algorithms:

- Betweenness Centrality
- Biconnected Components
- Bipartite Matching
- Bridge Detection
- Community Detection
- Cycle Detection
- Graph Coloring
- Katz Centrality
- Maximum Flow
- Node Similarity
- PageRank
- Union Find
- Dynamic Betweenness Centrality
- Dynamic Community Detection
- Dynamic node2vec
- Dynamic Katz Centrality
- Dynamic PageRank

A complete list of algorithms and implementation details within MAGE can be found at https://memgraph.com/docs/mage/algorithms.